# Cakephp file upload issue for number of files

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

upload plugin works excellent for me, but when I have multiple file upload-> select `30 images` (approx `15 MB`) -> Upload only `18-20 images`. May be issued with a number of files. post_max_size I have updated from 8M to 20M in php.ini . I have solved the same by using dropzone.js instead of simple file upload.It has no issue upload 100 files at a time. Still want to know why simple file upload is not working?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking post_max_size, memory_limit, blah blah blah? or even just looking at the log files?

Comment: I have done that. May be issued with a number of files. post_max_size I have updated from 8M to 20M. I have solved the same by using dropzone.js instead of simple file upload.It has no issue upload 100 files at a time. Still want to know why simple file upload is not working?